Necessity of pronoun "that" or "those" when comparing two things
We usually use "that" or "those" when we repeat the noun(s) used before especially in comparative sentences.
But what about in this sentence?

The intellectually inferior mice achieved comparable performance levels to their superiors.

Or do I have to say this?

The intellectually inferior mice achieved comparable performance levels to those of their superiors.

Is the first version wrong or unclear?

Or eliminate the clumsy verbosity.  "achieved comparable performance levels to their superiors" could be converted to "performed (almost?) as well as their superiors".


achieved performance comparable to that of their superiors
achieved performance levels comparable to those  of their superiors
performed (almost) as well as their superiors  NOTE: depends on what you mean by "comparable" --  the same, or close? 

Compare these actual attestations from Google Books showing the phrase headed by comparable coming after the first  noun-phrase comparand:

... perform services comparable to those rendered by Company A

United States Internal Revenue Bulletin (2006) - Issues 27-35 - Page 290

... price ranges comparable to those being relocated

Wisconsin State Highway 23, Fond Du Lac to Plymouth, Fond Du Lac and Sheboygan Counties, Wisconsin: Final Environmental Impact Statement (2010)

... characteristics comparable to those of advanced successional stages

Plant Functional Diversity: Organism traits, community structure, and ecosystem properties, page 16.  Eric Garnier, Marie-Laure Navas, Karl Grigulis (Oxford, 2016)
P.S. Here's an ngram showing the plural noun followed by the phrase headed by comparable side-by-side with comparable as premodifier of the plural noun followed by the prepositional phrase headed by to. For most of the 20th century the former has greatly outnumbered the latter form, though the latter form has begun to make some inroads recently: results comparable to those vs comparable results to those


The intellectually inferior mice achieved comparable performance levels to their superiors.

No.
It should be

The intellectually inferior mice achieved comparable performance levels to their superiorsʼ.


Oh, the possessive apostrophe but hidden in that snowstorm. Could you also say what is missing, in the answer. The first time I saw the post I presumed it was a formatting error.

@Mari-LouA The "snowstorm is the refusal of the coded bolding. "he intellectually inferior mice achieved comparable performance levels to their superiors' levels.

Don't really need that apostrophe.

Why? How are we to know if you are right. This sort of answer is worthless on this site.

@David That is a little harsh coming from a native speaker, especially as you have failed to observe the genitive in superiors' and "of their superiors" - a possessive in the second example -  it is a connection I expected readers to make. The answer I gave combines both variants.

@Greybeard — My criticism of your answer is that it is merely an assertion of opinion. There is no explanation of why you are right to allow the poster or anyone else to judge it or, even if correct, to learn why it is correct. That may be satisfactory if you are using your authority as a father to talk to your children, but you should know full well that SE expects more from answers. Sure, worthless per se is harsh if you are correct, but I qualified it by relating it to SE.
